# android: How to dial a number without using dial number pad while another call is in progress

Tags: android

I'm blocked at following issue,
My requirement is,

I'm connected to a call which is in progress, and while that in progress i want my app to automatically dial the number which is already copied at clipboard to the dialer.(paste/set directly to dialer)

To be specific,
Suppose we called to customer care of any mobile network provider then we usually get an message like "PRESS 2" "PRESS 3" like that..

Same way i want to dial/Press a predefined number which is on clipboard.

Can somebody help me how to do that ?

Thank you.